# Select child element, except first

Tags: css

In my app I have a a div, where I can load dynamically components. The structure after rendering looks like this:

```
<div class="component-holder">
   <custom-1></custom-1>
   <custom-2></custom-2>
   <custom-3></custom-3>
   <custom-4></custom-4>
</div>
```

I want to add a top margin to every component, except the first.
Current css:

```
.component-holder > *:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

It selects nothing.

Comment: What are your child elements?....`first-child` mighy be a better option.

Comment: Child elements are custom `angular` components. It could be anything. `<banner>` `<slider>`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.component-holder > *:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```